# Issue with background image stretching site on mobile devices

Tags: css, html, mobile-browser

My site looks fine when viewed on Desktop browser, but on mobile device the background image messes everything up and responsiveness is not achieved.

Site in question: http://www.victorfrolov.com

here's my code for the background image in body in css:

```
body {
     /* Location of the image */
    background-image: url('../img/image.jpg');

      /* Background image is centered vertically and horizontally at all times */
    background-position: center center;

      /* Background image doesn't tile */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

      /* Background image is fixed in the viewport so that it doesn't move when 
         the content's height is greater than the image's height */
    background-attachment: fixed;

      /* This is what makes the background image rescale based
     on the container's size */
    background-size: cover;

    /* Set a background color that will be displayed
     while the background image is loading */
    background-color: #464646;

    background-color:#FFF;
    /*font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;*/
    /*font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;*/
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    color:#3E404B;
}
```

This is what it looks like on a desktop (and shrinking/enlarging the page it works fine):

[image: desktop image]
and here's on mobile:

[image: mobile image]
and here is the parallax code, maybe this is the issue?

```
body,
html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 5%;
}

.slide {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    box-shadow: inset 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}
```

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: I recommend you to post a screenshot of your problem instead of a link to your page. It can be seen as spam content.

Answer (score 0):

```
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 320px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (orientation: portrait) {
body { width: 100%; max-width: 100%; height: auto;
 }
}
```

Or you may need to set a class for your img in your.       html and use .test class with the same media query, then use same size, but set (orientation: landscape)

Comment: the page is still all messed up, but now the background became white.

Comment: Please share your new code and i will try to help. I was on mobile when I first viewed and answered this.

Comment: I have viewed your page in mobile portrait and landscape. I would advise you do the same. No-repeat is not the issue here, but I need to see both the html and the css. You definitely need to set a max-width: of 100%;  somewhere and height: auto; , but I need to see the code to see where. That is why you have a mega horizontal scroll = nono on mobile and portrait.

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle with all my code: http://jsfiddle.net/2gduodvk/1/
under "css" there's 3 css files, one titled "style.css" which is first, the second, commented, is parallax.css, and the third is animations.css
@user3758480